# Can I use a third party Javascript library in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

for example mootools!!
It's comfortable for me to coding in js, but not for everyone obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly can. The best thing is to write yourself some nice [JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html), which encapsulate your access to the third-party library. That way, other developers - I assume that you are trying to set things up for a team - can interact with the third-party JS library without having to know a heap about it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, See here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what the question asked for?