# GWT and Firebase integration

Tags: gwt, firebase

Is it possible to use Firebase as backend for database, file-storage, authentication, etc, with GWT for web application projects?﻿

GWT is a development toolkit based on JAVA and Firebase provides javascript library. It seems like 3rd part lib can be included in GWT project as [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723193/can-i-use-a-third-party-javascript-library-in-gwt), but is it a common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, you found a nice example describing some key concepts like JSNI, overlay types and so on. I've used JQuery in a similar manner (later replaced it with GQuery though). There's a similar project exising for Firebase too, have you seen it?

https://github.com/thurn/firebase-xplatform

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will check it out.